# Cakephp default index action and paginator

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

By default the 'index' action in my EventsController (or any Controller) returns the full set of entries and I want to display only the events created by the currently logged in user (the associations are well defined and my events table has a foreign key `user_id`).

here is the default index action as generated from the cake bake console command:

```
class EventsController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
        $this->Event->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('events', $this->paginate());
    }
    ....
}
```

There might be something with the `$this->paginate()` that I don't understand, 'cause already I tried to retrieve the entries I need using `$events = $this->find('all',$options)` and it didn't do anything. Is there a way to specify my conditions as to which entries will be returned to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to set conditions to the pagination is in [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html). Basically, if you have the user id in a variable `$userID` and the events have a `user_id` column, you could do what you ask like this

```
$this->set('events', $this->paginate('Event', array('user_id'=>$userID)));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't feel comfortable with the paginator, this is basically what I was asking for and it works, thank you.